# All columns not present in create view filter option

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, filter

Trying to create a view which filters a specific columns with hyperlinks in it. I went to create view --> filter and that column does not appear in the drop down. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

By default, SharePoint does not support hyperlink column as filter.